# Match all possible combinations of substring in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

Assuming I have an input string like "auto encoder" and array of strings

```
const arr = ['autoencoder', 'auto-encoder', 'autoencoder']
```

I want the input string to match with all three in array.

I created regex

```
arr.some(word => word.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+|(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+))$/))
```

but seems it doesn't work as if I test it against an array with a single element like ['auto-encoder'] it returns nothing.

How can I achieve desired matching?

Comment: Do you need a regex specific solution? Also do  you mean `arr.find` which would be correct, by `arr.findall`? No such function exist in JavaScript itself.

Comment: @sçuçu That is incorrect. `Array.prototype.find` only returns the first match in the array. If you want multiple matches, you have to use `Array.prototype.filter` instead.

Comment: @sçuçu sorry, some instead of findall, ofcourse.

Comment: I do not say it would the correct answer, I meant it would be correct in itself, it would be correct in JavaScript.

Comment: Then you would get a boolean wit `some`, if it is ok for you.

Comment: I find the question a bit confusing you are first talking about that you have an input string, and an array of strings. You then ask how you can match the input string against the array of strings. Now for some reason you introduce a regex. To me it seems like you are looking for `arr.some(word => word == input)`. Why is the regex introduced? Am I understanding the question wrong?

Comment: `find` did find the first encounter in the array for your criteria by the way, `filter` would return a new array of matches, and `some` would return a boolean.

Comment: @sçuçu well, basically I want to match words with hyphens with words without them, i mean, if I enter word 'auto-encoder', and the array contains only 'auto encoder' or 'autoencoder' forms, the function must return True

Comment: Then you need a regex, as you did, not a specific input string but an array of them to test against your regex. Just for clarification.

Comment: @3limin4t0r the regex is needed as the input string may be 'auto-encoder', and the array may contain only non-hyphenated forms, but the function must behave as that's the same

Comment: I would say given you have the correct regex for your purpose, if you need an array of matches at the end use `filter`, or if you just want to know if some of the array elements match or not use `some`. If you wasnt to know if all elements match use `every`. Again `find` would only return first match.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function isIncluded(str, arr) {
  str = str.replace(/\W/g, '');
  return arr.some(e => (e.replace(/\W/g, '') === str));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your input is gonna be a string, not an array of strings. You have already the regex, you just need to define a function around it:

```
function f(word) {
  return word.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+|(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+))$/);
}
```

And if you rinput is gonna be an array you can use various array methods:
If you want a boolean answer if some elements match

```
function f(arr) {
  return arr.some(word => word.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+|(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+))$/));
}
```

If you want to know if all elements match use `every` instead of `some`

You have other options. For having the array of the matches use `filter`:

```
function f(arr) {
    return arr.filter(word => word.match(/^[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+|(?:\-[a-zA-Z]+)|(?:[a-zA-Z]+))$/));
}
```

You could answer your function(s) according to what you want to achieve with each one.

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing special characters (*non-word characters*) and comparing with the array?

```js
const arr = ['auto encoder', 'autoencoder'];

const fn = (s, a) => a.includes(s.replace(/\W/g, ''));


console.log(fn('auto-encoder', arr));
console.log(fn('a u t o e n c o d e r', arr));
console.log(fn('random', arr));
```